# Sending jquery array and receiving it in jsp

Tags: jquery, arrays, jsp

I stored some integer value in an array called myArray.  I want to use Ajax to send myArray to a jsp file (file.jsp).  I'm having trouble retrieving the data in jsp, as I always get null.  Here is my code:

```
var request = $.ajax({
   url: "file.jsp",
   type: "POST",
   data: {myArray:myArray},
   dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $("#abc").html( msg );
});
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Failed " + textStatus );
});
```

file.jsp

```
String myArray = request.getParameter("spArray");
```

My question is: How can I successfully pass myArray from jquery-Ajax and retrieve it in file.jsp?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.
I converted array to string (ie myArray.toString();) and sent through.

Now I have:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "file.jsp",
  type: "POST",
  data: {myArray:myArray.toString()},
  dataType: "html"
});
```

and picked it up in file.jsp as

```
String myArray = request.getParameter("spArray").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try change this parametrs in ajax configuration:

```
dataType:       'json',
headers:        {'Content-type' : "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
```

Comment: in jsp, value is still null

Comment: hmm, and now?
`data: JSON.stringify({myArray:myArray}),`

Comment: It doesn't seem to execute the ajax portion of the code.  Here is what I have now var request = $.ajax({
                        url: "file.jsp",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: JSON.stringify({myArray:myArray}),
                        ContentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    });

Comment: I tried this:

`var myArray = [1,2,3];

$.ajax({ url: "file.jsp", type: "POST", dataType: 'json', data: JSON.stringify({myArray:myArray}), ContentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8" });`

And the ajax was send and output is: '{"myArray":[1,2,3]}'

try look at firebug